# How to prevent Computer going into sleep mode after Youtube's "Are you still watching?" is on screen for a while

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, sleep, hibernate, youtube

Just like the question says, I have been experiencing issues watching YouTube through Chrome browser. Basically after a while Youtube/Chrome will put the pc to sleep without warning. Just to clarify, the computer acts like it's powered off, no fans running, nor HDD spinning.

The problem happen when I'm listening to music, a podcast or whatever, off of YouTube. Since I'm not physically near the PC, thus no using any input It will result on the typical message "Are you still watching?" after 45 mins or so. Usually I go and click continue and the video will keep playing till it prompts the same question. But sometimes I can't go to the computer right away because I'm entertained gluing wood or something with higher priority and let the message sit on the screen for while. But if I take too long the computer is already in sleep mode.

Since this behavior is extremely weird I have already done virus/malware that found nothing. Then I tried to replicated the conditions, making sure the only application running is Chrome while playing a video. It will always turn my computer to sleep If no input is received by the computer while the "Are still watching?" message is on screen.

I have tried searching the internet but I have failed to find this specific problem.

How can I prevent this behavior? Is there any config on Chrome that I'm missing? Will others Browser behave in the same way?

Just to clarify I don't have a problem with the "Are you still watching?" message, my problem is it puts my computer to sleep if don't react fast enough.

The machine were this happens is running Windows 10 and it's a desktop. The power config has been the same since I built the system. The only application putting the machine to sleep is Chrome/youtube.

The idea that a webpage, somehow, has the power to signal the computer to sleep through the web browser is super creepy.

Comment: Chrome cannot put your computer into Sleep. The OS manages power.

Comment: A website can tell a browser to prevent the machine from going to sleep and that website can tell the browser later that the machine can go to sleep but that website absolutely cannot put the machine to sleep. If your machine is going to a hybrid sleep state it’s configured to do so due to a Windows setting

Comment: You can also use a tool such as Don't Sleep, https://www.softwareok.com/?Download=DontSleep, or Caffeine, https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/, to keep a PC awake for a specified time.

Comment: @Bolong Yeah, that's what I thought but the combo Chrome/youtube does indeed makes my computer go to sleep. I have replicated this conditions many times and it always happens. Video goes long enough for "Are you still watching?", It stays on screen for a while and the computer decides to sleep.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No other application has this troublesome behavior. I do put my computer to sleep manually all the time but for some weird reason when I don't attend the "Are you still watching?" prompt, eventually it goes to sleep. I know for a fact that if I stop using Chrome/youtube and just Winamp for music, the computer stays awake. In fact the computer stays awake as long as Chrome doesn't have a video on youtube that prompts "Are you still watching?" message.

Comment: @Ramhound But that's the problem, I don't have such a power setting on. If boot the computer and login into my windows session, the computer will stay on. I'll try to replicate the problem on other browsers but it's going to take a few days.

Comment: @dmb - It’s impossible for YouTube by itself to cause this behavior. Something else is going on…

Comment: Please go to Windows' Power settings and take a screenshot. It should be something in this post: https://www.energystar.gov/products/low_carbon_it_campaign/power_management_computer/windows_10